# Jdeveloper query form

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper, jqueryform

I'm trying to create an adf query panel with table but I need to limit the search values as also the result values in the table.

For example:
 - I have a table with FName, LName, Dateofbirth, address, phone
 - I want that the values presented in the search form are FName, Lname
 - the values in the result table Fname, Lname, address, phone

I've checked several links including this one [enter link description here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how-to_tell_the_viewcriteria_a_user_chose_in_an_afquery_component)

But I can't understand how to limit the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, by not checking the attribute option 'Queryable'.
This way the it does not appear in the query form,only in the results table.
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of resources available on the internet on how to implement search functionality in ADF. here are few for your reference:

- http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/04/creating-simple-search-form-in-oracle.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAWSfO-7xR8
- http://adfnote.blogspot.com/2013/02/create-simple-search-form-in-oracle-adf.html

Normally a search functionality is implemented using a `View Critreia`, which is created on a `View Object`. It shows up in Data Control as a `Named Criteria` under your View Object instance.
While creating the view criteria you can specify the items that you would want to see in the panel as search fields.
When you use (drag and drop) your view criteria as an 'ADF Query Panel with Table' on a page, you get the option to specify the columns you want to see in the results table. You can restrict the number of columns there, or even afterwards by just removing the unwanted columns from your page.